# How to upgrade OpenSSL in MAMP

Tags: php, openssl, mamp

I am using MAMP 2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 - This comes with the OpenSSL extention for PHP, however only version 0.9 - I need to upgrade it to 1.0 - however I'm not sure how I would go about such a task. Can anybody help?

Comment: upgrade mamp, or compile the extension yourself. that's not a particularly easy thing to do when you're using a pre-packaged version of PHP.

Comment: I am using the latest edition of MAMP

Comment: Did you find some solution? I have same problem with MAMP 3.0.6 PHP 5.5.14 but OpenSSL only 0.9.8r... How I can update it plz?

Comment: have you maybe found a solution for that?

Comment: @MarcB: I'd like to try, so how could I do to re-compile the extension as you mentioned?