# How to update OpenSSL version from 0.9.8zg to 1.0.2e

Tags: macos, apache, ssl, openssl

In my MacBook Pro with El Capitan I have Apache Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) with OpenSSL/0.9.8zg which I need to update to a later version. I tried both to update openssl from brew and to build it. I downloaded the last version from [here](https://www.openssl.org/) and then I did:

- ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
- make
- make test
- make install

and everything seems to be fine but when I run Apache and I have a look at `phpinfo();` output I see that version used is still OpenSSL/0.9.8zg. 
Do you know how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Today, 21st July 2016, there's a MAMP 4 pre-release with openssl 1.0.2

https://www.mamp.info/en/pre-release.html

Comment: you can use "pmap" to see which openssl library is attached to Apache's process

Comment: @rkosegi I have run your command (which in Mac OS X is `vmmap pid_httpd) and this is what I've got:

Comment: __DATA                 00000001052f6000-00000001052f8000 [    8K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
__DATA                 00000001052f8000-00000001052fa000 [    8K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so __DATA                 00007fff74cf4000-00007fff74cfa000 [   24K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib

Comment: it uses the old library even if the binary is updated...do you know hot to change it?

Comment: Install Macports. It will modify your paths so Macport binaries are on-path first. Then, install openssl using `port install openssl`. It will install into `/opt/local/bin`. You ***cannot*** update OpenSSL located in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` because they are *not* binary compatible.

Comment: @jww  I had tried it but Apache still kept on pointing to the old version of openssl (0.9.8)...maybe because it's mod_ssl.so is linked to that...anyway thank you

Comment: @Lory - yes, of course it will. You can't swap out stuff the way you are trying to do it. There's no binary compatibility. If you attempt to force it, it will lead memory errors and unexplained crashes. Instead, install Apache through Macports, too. Then, disable OS X's built-in Apache and use your version in Macport's `/opt/local/bin`. Macport's config file will be located in `/opt/local/etc`, IIRC. I do similar all the time with OpenSSH servers on OS X.

Comment: Also, take a look at [apple install_name_tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+install_name_tool). Apple dylib's embed the full pathname in an EXE. Apple's Apache will always runtime-link to the downlevel version of OpenSSL because its using the ***install name***. You can change it with `install_name_tool` but it will break if the new dylib lacks binary compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have installed the new version of openssl but you are not pointing to it. Just make a soft link pointing to your binary file. 
I am not aware of mac file system but I can help you with linux filesystem. Concept is same.

try with :-

```
mv /path/to/current/openssl /home/user
ln -s /path/to/new-openssl-binary/ /path/to/current/openssl
```

you can check your path with this linux command `whereis openssl`

check your openssl version with `openssl version` command.

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. Unfortunately I had already tried to make a new synbolic link but it did not work. :( I guess the problem is really the openssl version with which Apache was built. Also the new Mamp Pro still uses openssl 0.9.8 but I'm developing for ios 9 that's why I need the latest version...

Comment: Inside /usr/bin I have two executables: openssl (version 1.0.2d) which was created as you said; and openssl_OLD (version 0.9.8zg) but this doesn't work...it still uses the OLD one..

Comment: that's what I did: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl`

Comment: Now you have new openssl version but apache is still using old openssl version. This is the issue?

Comment: can you post the output of `ldd /path/to/mod_ssl-module` command.

Comment: Running `ldd` against the mod_ssl.so file will tell you what libssl.so it's using, and where it'll be loaded from. Make sure you have the latest OpenSSL libraries in that location.

Comment: use `otool -L <file>` for mac

Comment: this is the output: `otool -L /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so
/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so:
 /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
 /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.0.0)`

Comment: anyway I'm an idiot...I've made a mess. Can you please have a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532646/macos-x-el-cpitan-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method

Comment: apache is still using the old libraries of openssl

Comment: I know... everything is useless

Comment: I can see only one option here. Recompile the apache withe new openssl

Comment: The problem now is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532646/macos-x-el-cpitan-symbol-not-found-sslv2-client-method in other words all apps using openssl don't work now...

Comment: I think you need to reinstall your mod_ssl and apache. Your system ssl libraries are somewhat messed up

Comment: Do you know how to re-install mod_ssl? Can you please explain me? Forgive me I'm an ignorant I know and I'm in panic...can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I searched about apache on mac OS X and it is not recommend to re-compile apache. Any further update will brake the apache and it will be difficult to debug or fix it.

Comment: I found this link helpful. http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Mac_OS_X_Unleashed&seqNum=212 , But you have to be careful before doing this. Mac OS X is a little bit complex and user does not have freedom to modify it.

Comment: ok, I am afraid I will have to install a new copy of el capitan...thank you anyway

Comment: One more thing, ask this question or migrate this question on http://apple.stackexchange.com.. somebody can give you solution

Comment: This link http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130481/how-to-upgrade-apache-2-2-to-2-4-in-macosx-mavericks answers might help you in future