# PHP 7.0.33 with sqlsrv gives error "SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]"

Tags: php, database, openssl, sqlsrv

I'm using sqlsrv module with PHP 7.0.33, Apache 2.2.34 on MacOS Catalina (10.15.7).

The execution of `sqlsrv_connect` in this code block

```php
$serverName = "192.168.4.14";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "mydatabase",
    "UID" => "myusername",
    "PWD" => "mypassword"
);
// Create connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

gives me the error

*[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]*

I have more versions of PHP installed on my Mac, so I supposed this was the cause of the error, but opening the info.php page, it tells me that the OpneSSL module is loaded:

[image]

Here are the details about `pdo_sqlsrv` module given by info.php:

[image]

And `sqlsrv` module:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion about what else may I check to found the cause of the error?

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: the info.php shows me that in the configure command was used `--with-openssl=/Applications/MAMP/Library` which is the v1.0.2o.

Comment: I got the same error (but on Debian), did you check https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1021? MacOS is based on Linux so it can help.

Comment: Thank you @qdequippe, but that link didn't help me, as I don't have the `CipherString` option in MAMP OpenSSL library. In my system I have openssl@1.1 installed with homebrew and I'd only like that MAMP uses that instance of OpenSSL and not the one came with MAMP package.

Comment: Check if you have openSSL1.0 installed, not the php extension but the library itself on your system

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` to check which versions are available

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873107/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-mamp

Comment: Thank you @mahen3d, but ...Damn..... I've followed all the instructions, but phpinfo continue to show openssl version OpenSSL1.0.2o 27 March 2018... and the Openssl default config sa /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf. It seems impossible to tell MAMP to use another openssl library

Comment: @YouriKoeman, I've got openssl 1.1.1k in `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/bin/openssl`, as it says my `which openssl`

Comment: Adding more info: phpinfo shows me OpenSSL/1.1.1k in curl section, but OpenSSL 1.0.2o in openssl section... I've tried to execute the sqlsrv_connect, but I got the same error "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [OpenSSL library could not be loaded, make sure OpenSSL 1.0 or 1.1 is installed]"

Comment: I am afraid I am forced to recompile apache with openssl version 1.1.1 as the error doesn't seem to be related to curl's openssl version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved!!!!
As reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/37.

In `/usr/local/opt` homebrew has created the symlink `openssl@1.1`.

The issue was related to the impossibility for the Microsoft driver to read a dir with the format `opnessl@1.1`.

The solution is so simple as recreating the symlink omitting the `@1.1` suffix:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k /usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Thank you all for your contributions!

Comment: 2 entire days I wasted on this crap. Thank you

Comment: omg ... finally found solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem is that you don't have the correct version of the OpenSSL libs installed on your machine (seems to be a issue on catalina).

#### Step 1: Check if you have the correct version installed.

Run the following command (assuming the location for macOS): `ls -l /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

if this does not work, run the following command: `openssl version`

This should show which versions of OpenSSL libraries you have installed.
If you have `1.0` or `1.1` you are done

#### Step 2: Install or upgrade

If you have openssl installed (but not the right version), upgrade it with `brew upgrade openssl`

If you dont have openssl installed, install it with `brew install openssl`

#### Step 3 Test

After these steps this error should be resolved

Comment: `openssl version` gives me `OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021`, but the problem, as you can see from the screenshots in my question, is that MAMP is using its own library OpenSSL 1.0.2o. And the other question is: why, if MAMP uses a 1.0 version, I get that error message?